# Scuplting for Beginners

Tags: sculpting, zbrush

What are some free sculpting tutorials for absoute begineers in sculpting, Where each brushes explained in details with examples?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! Asking for tutorials or other resources is actually considered off topic here. You're better off asking on a forum or searching online. There is a list of resources that may have something useful though, found here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender

Comment: If you have specific questions, such as the difference between 2 brushes, or how a specific brush works, you're more than welcome to ask that here. In general, the more specific the question the better.

Comment: watch those ones (one is a bit old but nice!): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAGWu08oWAM  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZnUgt659oI